# Is it possible to restore Whatsapp Data from Google's backup, when it was backed up but Whatsapp just wiped it recently?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, google-account

Is it possible to restore Whatsapp Data from Google's backup, when it was backed up but Whatsapp just wiped it recently?

What happened was I had whatsapp on my Oppo Phone, and my Laptop.

I dropped my Opp Phone on a rainy day, and it broke and got wet inside and doesn't work right.

I have a number of Google accounts.

So I pulled out another phone, a Moto phone, And I put whatsapp on there. And I pulled up whatsapp on my laptop and saw all my messages and whatsapp groups.

I then moved my SIM card from the broken Oppo phone, to the Moto phone. And a message appeared on my laptop whatsapp saying to link it to my mobile.. Also some message appeared on my mobile saying "restore now 500MB or I don't get another chance".  I wasn't sure if the 500MB was my backup or not 'cos 500MB seems maybe not that much. I didn't say yes or no, I just pushed the back arrow.

I went through the process on the laptop about linking, then both got wiped.. The phone lists all groups with no messages in them, and no chat messages.. As does the laptop.

So it seems that when I didn't say Yes to that restore now message. Then it wiped my backup.

I'm wondering if  Google has a backup made by whatsapp  from e.g.  Before Today, that I can go back to?

It's pretty bad that whatsapp chooses to wipe a backup rather than create a new backup on the account.

Comment: Check [the backup inside Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/backups). Is it still there? Also, check the phone number to which it is linked. Otherwise, I'm afraid there's no way to restore since the backup is only stored there.

Comment: @AndrewT. it is still there on google drive , but I can't seem to copy it off via google takeout or by right clicking